# Creating a custom UITableViewCell with horizontal scroll using Interface Builder and as little code as possible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

We are implementing a table that contains a few cells that need to be able to scroll horizontally.

We managed to make this work programatically by adding the UIScrollView to the cell's contentView using code similar to this one:

```
UIScrollView *horizScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200)];
horizScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(2000, 100);
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 80)];
[label setText:@"horizontal scroll sample"];
[horizScrollView addSubview:label];
[cell.contentView addSubview:horizScrollView];
```

But it does not work if the ScrollView is added using Interface Builder and creating an IBOutlet to be able to implement whatever remaining code is left (set the ScrollView's contentSize for example). The custom cell's NIB structure looks like this in IB (sorry, it looks crude but I can't post images yet):

```
Horizontal Scroll Cell
|- Content View
   |- Scroll View
      |- Label
```

All solutions regarding this scenario we have seen are code related.

Does anyone know if the Interface Builder approach is viable, and if not, why is it not possible?

Answer (score 0):

For Horizontal scroll, go for CollectionView. Its really easy to implement & completely customisable. Here is a [good tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12) to start with it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will take a look into this approach. As far as I understand this option implies replacing the TableView in the ViewController with a CollectionView, as opposed to something else like replacing the ScrollView in the custom cell's NIB structure (shown above in the question) with said CollectionView. Is this correct?